# Jquery selecting ajax loaded element

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui

I am building a Hybrid App and i use ajax to load new pages But i am unable to select a image  loaded via ajax  here is my code:

```
$('.user-image').attr('src',data['img']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for selecting src attribute of img tag having class `user-image`.

```
$('.user-image').attr('src');
```

Comment: but i am not clicking on image than how can use this ?

Comment: Click is not required..Its javascript, you can write this anywhere and get image URL. Img tag should have class user-image

Comment: can you give any example ?

Comment: i want to change image src

Comment: Show.me.ur html where younwant to update image src ?